# unit test get url with multiple querystring params

Tags: regex, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am unit testing a get request that has two querystring params, I can't for the life of me figure out how to write the expect get correctly

```
describe('CostEffectivenessService#getCostEffectivenessChartData', function() {

    it('should request correct url', function() {
        expect(api.GET_COST_EFFECTIVENESS_CHART_DATA).toBe('CostEffectiveness/GetCostEffectivenessChartData');
    });

    it('should get cost effectiveess chart data', function() {
        $httpBackend.expectGET(/CostEffectiveness\/GetCostEffectivenessChartData\?effectiveTime=*\&fiscalYear=2014/)
            .respond([{}, {}, {}, {}]);            

        var promise = costEffectivenessService.getCostEffectivenessChartData(2014),
            results = null;

        promise.then(function(res) {
            results = res;

        });

        $httpBackend.flush();

        expect(results.lengths).toBe(4);
    });
```

results in this error

> Error: Unexpected request: GET CostEffectiveness/GetCostEffectivenessChartData?effectiveTime=2015-05-01T15:33:11.590Z&fiscalYear=2014
>       Expected GET /CostEffectiveness/GetCostEffectivenessChartData\?effectiveTime=*\&fiscalYear=2014/

can any body help me out please!!!

Comment: I think this should be `=.*?` rather than `=*`

Comment: YES!!!! @ExplosionPills

Answer (score 1):

Your request regex has `=*` which is "zero or more `=`" which is not the format you want.  Instead you can use `=.*?` which is "`=` followed by zero or more characters, reluctantly"